# How to display (or loop through) a stack in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to c++ and am trying to figure out how to display the contents of my stack after running it through a program.

```
int main(){
  int userInput;
  Stack st1,st2;
  cin>>userInput;
  int i,topStack;
  while(userInput!=-9){
    while(userInput>0){
      st1.push(userInput);
      topStack=st1.pop()
      st2.push(topStack);
  }
    if(userInput<0){
      for(i=0;i<(-userInput);++i){
        st2.pop();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to see what st2 looks like after I input values. Not quite sure how to do that and/or if it is possible. Resources would be more than appreciated!

Here is the custom class definition:

```
class ListNode{
  public:
    int content;
    ListNode* pNext;
};
class Stack{
  private:
    ListNode* top;
  public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
    int pop();
    void push(int);
};
Stack::Stack(){
  top=nullptr;
}
void Stack::push(int x){
  ListNode *newNode;
  newNode=new ListNode;
  newNode->content=x;
  newNode->pNext=top;
  top=newNode;
}
int Stack::pop(){
  int fR=-17; //empty stack
  if(top!=nullptr){
    ListNode* newNode;
    newNode=top;
    top=top->pNext;
    fR=newNode->content;
    delete newNode;
  }
  return fR;
}
Stack::~Stack(){
  while(top!=nullptr){
    pop();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `Stack`?  Is it a typedef to a standard library class, or is it a custom class?  If the former, you should be able to iterate through it; if the latter, it would likely depend on whether the custom class provides iterators or not (or possibly it provides an `operator<<` but not iterators, etc.).

Comment: It is a custom class. Should I iterate through in the class definition? Something alone the lines of cout the values?

Comment: If it's a custom class, we would need to see at least the class definition in order to have any idea whether the interface provides anything which might allow you to do this.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I added the custom class.

Comment: It looks like the class doesn't provide any way to iterate through or output the contents of the stack.  So, you would need to extend the class to add something along these lines.

Comment: How would you recommend going about that. Have the final stack be input into a method then pop into a cout to display the values?

Comment: Add some const_iterator support so you can read the stack for debugging, but not modify it.

Comment: Why do you implement your `Stack` as a linked list (linked lists are bad for performance)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly minimal implementation of an iterator class to allow viewing the contents of a `Stack` object.

I've also made some changes in the existing code to be more in line with modern C++ best practices.  In particular, you should hardly ever be using raw `new` and `delete` directly, so I've updated the code to use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

stack_iterator.hpp:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>

#pragma once

class Stack {
private:
    struct ListNode {
        int content;
        std::unique_ptr<ListNode> pNext;
    };

public:
    Stack() = default;
    Stack(const Stack&) = delete;
    Stack(Stack&&) = delete;
    Stack& operator=(const Stack&) = delete;
    Stack& operator=(Stack&&) = delete;

    void push(int);
    int pop();

    class const_iterator {
    public:
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = const int;
        using pointer = const int*;
        using reference = const int&;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

        const_iterator() = delete;
        const_iterator(const const_iterator&) = default;
        const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator&) = default;

        // Constructor making a const_iterator pointing to a particular
        // list node.
        const_iterator(ListNode*);

        // Pre-increment operator, e.g. called by ++i
        const_iterator& operator++();

        // Post-increment operator, e.g. called by i++
        const_iterator operator++(int);

        // Deference operator, e.g. called by *i
        reference operator*() const;

        // Comparison operators
        bool operator==(const const_iterator&) const;
        bool operator!=(const const_iterator&) const;

    private:
        ListNode* pNode;

        friend class Stack;
    };

    // Accessors to create iterators to start and end of stack.
    // Note that the stack is traversed from most recent to least
    // recent entries.  Also note that a pop() operation will invalidate
    // any iterator referring to the most recent entry of the stack.
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<ListNode> top;
};
```

stack_iterator.cpp:

```
#include "stack_iterator.hpp"

void Stack::push(int x) {
    auto newNode = std::make_unique<ListNode>();
    newNode->content = x;
    newNode->pNext = std::move(top);
    top = std::move(newNode);
}

int Stack::pop() {
    static constexpr int retvalOnEmpty = -17;

    auto oldTop = std::move(top);
    if (oldTop != nullptr) {
        top = std::move(oldTop->pNext);
        return oldTop->content;
    }
    return retvalOnEmpty;
}

// pre-increment operator
Stack::const_iterator& Stack::const_iterator::operator++() {
    pNode = pNode->pNext.get();
    return *this;
}

// post-increment operator
Stack::const_iterator Stack::const_iterator::operator++(int) {
    auto ret_iterator = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return ret_iterator;
}

// dereference operator
Stack::const_iterator::reference Stack::const_iterator::operator*() const {
    return pNode->content;
}

// comparison operators
bool Stack::const_iterator::operator==(const Stack::const_iterator& other) const {
    return this->pNode == other.pNode;
}

bool Stack::const_iterator::operator!=(const Stack::const_iterator& other) const {
    return this->pNode != other.pNode;
}

// semi-private constructor making an iterator pointing to a particular ListNode
Stack::const_iterator::const_iterator(ListNode* i_node) :
    pNode(i_node)
{ }

Stack::const_iterator Stack::begin() const {
    return Stack::const_iterator{top.get()};
}

Stack::const_iterator Stack::end() const {
    return Stack::const_iterator{nullptr};
}
```

Example main program showing how to use the iterators:

```
#include "stack_iterator.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    Stack s;
    s.push(3);
    s.push(5);
    s.push(-4);

    std::cout << "Contents of stack: ";
    for (auto n : s)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Alternative
    std::cout << "Contents of stack, using ostream_iterator: ";
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches using the standard library's containers:

1. Give up your own implementation of a stack entirely, and using the one available as part of the standard library: [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack). To display the elements, do something like:

   ```
   void print(std::ostream& os, std::stack s, char delimiter = ' ')        
   {
       if (not s.empty()) { 
           std::cout << s.top();
       }
       while (not s.empty()) {
           std::cout << delimiter << s.top();
       }
   }
   ```

   since you're passing the stack by *value*, you're really making a copy of it.
2. Use your own stack implementation, but implement it over an [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), and expose the list's iterators (similar to Daniel Schepler's answer but without most of the hard work...).

Of course, it's better to implement an `operator<<` then a print function, but the principle is the same.